# Select users which last message is older than 30 days

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table `messages` with the columns `user_id`, `message`,`created_at`, `type`

I need to select ALL users which last posted a message of type=1 more than 30 days ago

I've tried:

`SELECT user_id FROM messages WHERE type=1 AND MAX(created_at) < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 day)`
Which has given me the error:

`invalid use of group function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to the use of MAX which is an aggregation function in the where clause. It is correct to use MAX but for each user. That is, first group by user and then use the MAX condition. Try:

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM messages 
WHERE type=1 
group by user_id
having MAX(created_at) < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 day)
```